# Resolve Go package naming conflict when compiling protobuf definitions with different packages

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I'm using protoc to create some DTOs. The definitions are in the following structure:

```
/protobuf
|-- common.proto
|-- /api
    |-- /service
        |-- csvdownload.proto
```

My `csvdownload.proto` looks like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package protobuf.api.service;

import "common.proto";

option go_package = ".;service"; // golang

message CsvExportRequest {
    Common.Currency exportCurrency = 2;
    Common.Decimal rounding = 3;
}
```

and the stub of `common.proto` looks like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package protobuf;

option go_package = ".;gopb"; // golang
```

I'm attempt to compile `csvdownload.proto` by running the following command from the `/protobuf` directory:

```
protoc --go_out=gopb --go_opt=paths=source_relative .\api\service\csvdownload.proto
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> protoc-gen-go: Go package "." has inconsistent names gopb (common.proto) and service (api/service/csvdownload.proto)

I assume this to mean that the code cannot be generated because `common.proto` and `csvdownload.proto` have declared different packages but I'm not sure that should make a difference and, from my understanding of how Protobuf works, it shouldn't hinder my ability to compile `csvdownload.proto`. What am I doing wrong here?

Any help in dealing with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must change your directory structure to something like this:

```
/protobuf
|-- /common
    |-- common.proto
|-- /api
    |-- /service
        |-- csvdownload.proto
```

also, I suggest you add a real package address for `common.proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";
package protobuf;

option go_package = "myProject.com/proto/common"; // golang
```

then you can import this common to your other protos like this.

```
import "common/common.proto";
```

the generating code is(it is the full request you want(I think))

```
protoc --proto_path=../base_directory/protobuf/api/service/ --proto_path=../base_directory/protobuf/ --go_out=plugins=grpc:./the/generated/path/you/want/directory ../base_directory/protobuf/api/service/csvdownload.proto
```

Comment: So, a valid project name would be something like `github.com/myproject/proto/common` then?

Comment: @Woody1193 yes, this is proto package name. your generated protos like csvdownload will be using this package