# Go proto: File not found

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, proto, grpc-go

I have been trying to run below command

```
protoc   -I ./interfaces/  -I ${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate@v0.1.0 -I ${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/gogo/protobuf@v1.3.2 -I ${GOPATH}pkg/mod/github.com/x --gogo_out=. --go_out="plugins=grpc:./generated"   --validate_out="lang=go:./generated" ./interfaces/test_server/*.proto
```

Getting below error

github.com/x/customValidation/**validators.proto: File not found**.
test_server/test.proto:5:1: Import "github.com/x/customValidation/validators.proto" was not found or had errors.

I can see the proto file is in this location -> github.com/x/customValidation/validators.proto
and locally it got saved at -> pkg\mod\github.com\x\custom!validation@v0.0.0-20210817213416-5eb0b8804c6f

I also tried with --proto_path command still getting same error that proto file is not found

```
protoc  \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}/src \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/gogo/protobuf@v1.3.2 \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate@v0.1.0 \
--proto_path=${GOPATH}pkg/mod/github.com/x \
--proto_path=. --gogo_out=. --govalidators_out=gogoimport=true:. --go_out="plugins=grpc:./generated" --validate_out="lang=go:./generated" ./interfaces/test_server/*.proto
```

Comment: The protobufs to be compiled (i.e. `./interfaces/test_server/*.proto`) must appear in one of the `proto_path`s too. I think you may need to use absolute paths too i.e. `${PWD}/interfaces` instead of `./interfaces`. So, you'll want `... --proto_path=${PWD}/interfaces/test_server ... ${PWD}/interfaces/test_server/*.proto`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [protoc: Go package has inconsistent package names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443549/protoc-go-package-has-inconsistent-package-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like an issue with paths.  The path must be accurate relative to where you are executing or an absolute path.